# how to test Observable.combineLatest

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

```
Observable.combineLatest(userService.getCurrentUser(),someDataService.getAllData(),
    (currentUser, someData) => {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
        this.someData = someData;
}).subscribe()
```

I am using this code in my `ngOninit` function int my component and I need to test it using karma.
how do you suggest to do it?